# Java keyTool - append primary/secondary intermediate certificates to key store

Tags: java, ssl, certificate

I have already created a keystore (server.jks in the image) having imported the relevant key-pair.

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore server.p12 -destkeystore server.jks -srcstoretype pkcs12
```

I need to append intermediate certificates to it using the java keytool.

Using KeyStore explorer tool on windows, I can append certificates following the right click context menu, just like in the attached image.

[image]

After adding the primary/intermediate certificates following the Append Certificate option, I can see it on the KeyStore explorer like a tree.

```
---primary intermediate certificate
     |---secondary intermediate certificate
           |---my server certificate
```

I am very much interested in knowing how this can be done, using the 'Java KeyTool' on the (LINUX) command line.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If someone visited this page somehow, please do find the Proper answer provided by Bruno with this Stackoverflow link.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23686259/java-keytool-append-primary-secondary-intermediate-certificates-to-key-store?noredirect=1#comment36430812_23686259